# Servlet - how to receive a zip file

Tags: java, servlets

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to code a servlet which can receive a zip file in http request?

I googled but didn't find anything. If a zip file can't be sent using http request then please suggest an alternative

I'm not asking for examples on how to upload a file using a servlet. I need to know if a file can be sent to a servlet and if yes, then how?

For instance, if a string is sent to a servlet and you use the following code to get it:
 String value = req.getParameter(name);

but what if a file is sent? Can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered Apache Commons FileUpload?  http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Answer (score 2):

Any file can be uploaded, there's no distinction if it is a zip or text file.

Just google "servlet file upload" for many results.
One example is this: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet)

Comment: I'm not asking for examples on how to upload a file using a servlet. I need to know if a file can be sent to a servlet and if yes, then how?

Comment: It is yes, and the link I gave explains how. Receiving a file through http request equals uploading a file. But the request keyword here is in "network" mean, so that request should be a multipart formdata request. You can't send or receive a file with GET requests. In addition, you can even simulate the client-end so the client doesn't necessarily send the data through a browser or html interface.